# Export jmeter test result into mysql database

Tags: mysql, jmeter

I need to export my jmeter test results which I save as a csv file into mysql database.
The columns i want to export are `response time (t), timestamp (ts), average, throughput, latency, in and max`.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you are encountering or the *specific* part where you are stuck at?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'fred.txt' INTO TABLE my_table;
```

or

```
LOAD DATA INFILE fred.csv
INTO table my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(
  response,
  timest,
  avg,
  thru,
  lat,
  in,
  max
)
SET
  response= @var1,
  timest = @var2,
  etc
```